# Is there a way to use Ecto with cloud based SQL?

Tags: sql-server, elixir, ecto

Currently I am making an app where I want to have all the dependancies as orderly as possible. With my app running Elixir on Google's Compute engine, I think, for my (SQL) database, to use the PaaS solution that Google Cloud itself provides.

This being the case, I went looking for an adaptor and unfortunately found none. However, under the impression that SQL is itself a standard, I wonder how hard it might be to use an existing adapter like `Ecto.Adapters.Postgres` or `Ecto.Adapters.SQL` with the login information of my platform.

Is this something that is possible, and furthermore what type of protocol is implied by using the predominant adapters? Is it simply a RESTful api or is it something a little more proprietary to postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Google Cloud SQL (it's unclear from your question) then judging by this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/) and especially this passage:

"administer your relational MySQL databases on Google Cloud Platform"

then you should be able to use the [MySQL adapter](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.MySQL.html) for Ecto. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question and if I am, then please add some detail to your question so we can give you a better answer.

If you've already researched this option then please provide more detail about what's not working for you.